# CSS3 transform doesn't work on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a simple code that works on Firefox and IE11 ,but it doesn't work on Chrome.
it's a simple div that when the page loads it must 'fade in' and 'on click' must 'fade out'.
it's the code :
HTML

```
<div class="BoxContainer">    
      <div class="Box " id="Box1">
        <div class="LargeTile Tile Tile_SKY">
            <div class="BoxTitle">
                Search
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.BoxContainer{
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:15%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    perspective: 1000;
}
#Box1
{
    top:10px;
    left:0px;
}
.Tile_SKY{
    background:#2a7fed url('imgs/tiles/sky.png');
    border:2px solid #4399f1;
}
.LargeTile{
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.LargeTile .BoxTitle{
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    color:#fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 5px;
}
.LargeTile .TileImage{

    width: 45%;
    height: 45%;
    margin: 25% auto;
}
.fadeOutback{
 animation: fadeOutback 0.3s ease-out 1 normal forwards;
}
.fadeInForward{
  /*remember: in the second animation u have to set the final values reached by the first one*/
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.75);
  animation: fadeInForward .25s cubic-bezier(.03,.93,.43,.77) .2s normal forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeOutback{
  0% {transform: translateX(-2em) scale(1); opacity:1;}
  70% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  95% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  100% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes fadeInForward{
  0% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
  100% {transform: translateZ(0) scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Box1').addClass('fadeInForward').removeClass('fadeOutback');
    $('.Tile').on('click',function(){
    $('#Box1').removeClass('fadeInForward').addClass('fadeOutback'); 
    });
});
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf46T/10/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the vendor prefixes on your transforms, animations, keyframes, etc.
Here's an updated version of your example that works using the keyframes with vendor prefixes.

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf46T/13/)**</kbd>

```
@keyframes fadeOutback{
  0% {transform: translateX(-2em) scale(1); opacity:1;}
  70% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  95% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  100% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOutback{
  0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-2em) scale(1); opacity:1;}
  70% {-webkit-transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  95% {-webkit-transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0.6); opacity:0.5;}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
}
@keyframes fadeInForward{
  0% {transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
  100% {transform: translateZ(0) scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInForward{
  0% {-webkit-transform: translateZ(-5em) scale(0); opacity:0;}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1); opacity:1;}
}
```

I also forked off your example and made a similar version that uses transitions instead of keyframes. There's a little less control over the animation, but it's probably a cleaner solution.

<kbd>**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAb2Q/1/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="box1" class="box hidden">
        <span class="box-title">Search</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.box-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

.box {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
    transition: all 400ms ease;

    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);

    opacity: 1;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    border:2px solid #4399f1;
    background: #2a7fed;
    display: block;
}

.box.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
```

JS

```
$('#box1').removeClass('hidden');

$('#box1').on('click',function(){
    $('#box1').addClass('hidden'); 
});
```

Comment: I would add a reference for browsers support: http://caniuse.com/#search=3d%20transform%7Canimations

Answer (score -2):

Is there a reason you want to use both Jquery and CSS3? If you're going to use JS at all you might as well use it to fade the box in and out very simply.

set `#Box1` to `display: none;` in your CSS and then add the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#Box1').delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");

    $('.Tile').click(function(){
        $('#Box1').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

This will fade in `#Box1` on page load and when you click fade it out.

**UPDATE** I added a delay on the fade in because it was happening too quickly. I Updated my JS above and new fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmore009/c2tFt/3/)

Comment: Tnx but this isn't what I need.I want to fade and rescale just like previous answer that solved my problem.

Comment: Probably because of jQuery animation, while CSS animation was requested, which is much faster: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/

Comment: ok well your post didn't say that. In any case I understand the other post got it working, but doing this with CSS3 and adding/removing classes with Jquery is not a very efficient way of doing things. Jquery is more than capable of handling all of that and would be a much better choice than a mixture of the two (considering you need to use it for the click function anyways)

Comment: My post? I'm only trying to explain why your answer may be not as good as you think it is.

Comment: @Pavlo from your link "You need to keep in mind that a fair amount of people still use Internet Explorer 7 and 8, so you should use jQuery if your animations absolutely need to work the same in those older browsers." I'm all for using CSS3 instead of Jquery, but if you're going to run jquery at all, just use it to accomplish everything, no reason to have it handle parts and CSS3 handle the rest

Comment: and no, the first response was to SNT.

Comment: The article is 15 months old, that part is not true nowadays.

Comment: what part? That IE 7 and 8 dont support CSS3? uh, ok. What did you post the article for if it's so old?

Comment: In any case, you can disagree with me, I just don't believe in using jquery and css to accomplish something jquery can do alone. SNT did not specify that he wanted the boxes to resize and fade in, only fade in. So I don't think this answer warranted a down vote. On top of that I specifically asked in my first line "Is there a reason you want to use both Jquery and CSS3?" and was not given an answer as to why this was important.